# Spinner value Changing based on parent spinner value changing

Tags: android

hi everyone ,
            I have three spinners .In that i want to change second spinner value change based on first spinner value and third spinner change based on second spinner value all values are fetched and displayed from database.I am using ArrayAdapter .I was searching for the last two weeks . But i dont get solution kindly help me i am running out of time pls.

Comment: Dear all Pls help me i ma running out of time . kindly give full source to execute the program pls

Comment: Why you are displaying spinners? If you are using AsyncTask then you can override method onProgressUpdate() to get the progress of the task.

Comment: @venkateswaran see my answer may be help you.

Comment: @venkateswaran you got a solution ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

may be this will help,

```
ArrayAdapter<String> secondspinnerAdapter;
ArrayAdapter<String> firstspinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                firstspinnervalue);
        first_spinner.setAdapter(firstspinnerAdapter);
        firstspinnerAdapter 
                .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);


firstspinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    // get data from database add to arraylist

                      secondspinnerAdapter = new
                      ArrayAdapter<String>( mainActivity.this,
                      android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,   arraylistvalue);
                      second_spinner.setAdapter(secondspinnerAdapter);
                      second_spinner.setSelection(arg2, false);
                      secondspinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource
                      (android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```

first spinner item is selected, then get data from database and fill arraylist and set secondspinner.

same way follow second spinner item selected.

Comment: @rajehwaran i got an answer from ur snippet thankyou so much for your help

Answer (score 4):

you have to just do set adapter like:

```
package com.example.mapsdemo;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Spinner spin1;
    private Spinner spin2;

    ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> b = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> c = new ArrayList<String>();

    // private ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        spin1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        spin2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);

        fillarray();

        spin1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, a));
        /*
         * spin2.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
         * android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, b));
         */

        spin1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int pos,
                    long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (pos == 0) {
                    spin2.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                            MainActivity.this,
                            android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, b));
                } else {
                    spin2.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                            MainActivity.this,
                            android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, c));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
    }

    private void fillarray() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        a.clear();
        a.add("a");
        a.add("b");
        a.add("c");
        a.add("d");
        a.add("e");

        b.clear();
        b.add("1");
        b.add("2");
        b.add("3");
        b.add("4");

        c.clear();
        c.add("Android");
        c.add("ios");
    }

}
```

your layout file like:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```